# Yii2 - Inline Validator Error

Tags: php, yii2

If I try use the example in the official documentation to create an inline validator using an anonymous function I get an error complaining about the 3rd parameter when I try save the record. but it goes away when I leave it out. is it likely I am using the sample wrong?
Here is the code sample:

```
// an inline validator defined as an anonymous function
['token', function ($attribute, $params, $validator) {
    if (!ctype_alnum($this->$attribute)) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'The token must contain letters or digits.');
    }
}],
```

Here is the basic error:
Missing argument 3 for app\models\MyModel::app\models{closure}()

Just wondering if I am using it wrong.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#inline-validators[enter link description here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#inline-validators)

Comment: I have worked out the answer to my own question. The third parameter is new to 2.0.11 and I was running 2.0.10. It mentions it just below the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read a bit below the [link i posted initially](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#inline-validatorsenter%20link%20description%20here) that it is a new parameter added in 2.0.11 (I was running 2.0.10).

Note: Since version 2.0.11 you can use `yii\validators\InlineValidator::addError()` for adding errors instead. That way the error message can be formatted using `yii\i18n\I18N::format()` right away. Use `{attribute}` and `{value}` in the error message to refer to an attribute label (no need to get it manually) and attribute value accordingly:

`$validator->addError($this, $attribute, 'The value "{value}" is not acceptable for {attribute}.');`

Comment: By seeing your reputation, I believe in the end you will answer your own question. :)